# UNITY Why when i look down everything becomes bright?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is an example of such a case.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

When creating an HDRP project, the "HDRPDefaultResources" folder appears in the file manager, in it, in the "Materials" folder, there is the "HDRPDefaultSettings" file, opening it in the inspector, scrolling down, there will be the "Exsposure" setting, in it, in the "Mode" section, select "Fixed", and in the "Fixed Exposure" section choose an exposure for your project.